# Ajax loader image is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, css

I want to show ajax loader image.In my rails app i have three different form in a single page.All those page is ajaxified and they are hitting the same controller action.I have added the ajax loader image but when i press one form then the image is shown to all of form in the page.

my js file:
        $("#loading-password").hide();
        $("#loading-address").hide();
        $("#loading").hide();

```
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){

      $("#loading").show();
      $("#loading-password").hide();
      $("#loading-address").hide();

      }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
       $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");

});


     $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){

       $("#loading-password").show();
       $("#loading-address").hide();
       $("#loading").hide();


     }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
       $("#loading-password").fadeOut("slow");


});



   $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading-address").show();
    $("#loading-password").hide();
    $("#loading").hide();

    }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
     $("#loading-address").fadeOut("slow");

   });
```

I have three different div for three form.I dont know whats wrong here.

please help guys .

Answer (score 0):

With `ajaxsend` you are binding those functions to every AJAX call, as stated [in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/):

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSend() method are executed at this time.

Basically you're binding 3 functions for each `ajaxsend` event.
To do what you have in mind I would suggest the following:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#loading-password").hide();
    $("#loading-address").hide();

  if ( settings.data === "first_form_data" ) {
    $("#loading").show();

  } else if (settings.data === "second_form_data"){

    $("#loading-password").show();

  } else if( settings.data === "third_form_data"){

    $("#loading-address").show();
  }
});

$(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
  if ( settings.data === "first_form_data" ) {
    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");

  } else if (settings.data === "second_form_data"){

    $("#loading-password").fadeOut("slow");

  } else if( settings.data === "third_form_data"){

    $("#loading-address").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
```

Basically I'm binding a single function to the event and check the data to understand which form has been submitted. Same thing also with the `ajaxComplete`.

In the `ajaxSend` documentation page they are using the URL to discover which call is sending the data, but in your case it won't work as long as I understand because they're all hitting the same route. Have a look [at the `settings` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information to spot the right form.

Comment: Thanks @MarcocI.I solved my problem.I changed my js code.I used form submit event.Each form has an Id.Then i called submit event on the respective form and then fadeIn the respective ajax loader div.

Answer (score 0):

Okay then i solved the problem.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$("#loading-password").hide();
$("#loading-address").hide();
$("#loading").hide();

});



$('#main-info').submit( function() {
$(this).children(".main-div").children("#loading").show();
});
$('#edit-password').submit( function() {
$(this).children(".main-div").children("#loading-password").show();
});
$('#edit-address').submit( function() {
$(this).children(".main-div").children("#loading-address").show();
});
```

Here i've completely removed the ajax event and choose to form submit event.Now when i submit a form that will trigger the ajax loader image respectively.Do remember that there is div with class main-div under each form and my ajax loader div is inside this div.Now its rocking.